# What is the output to the print statement?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Shouldn't the output be 6 as it should print B[0][2] ?
The output is coming out to be 4. which is B[1][0]

```
main()
{    
    int B[2][3]={2,3,6,4,5,8};
    printf("%d",**B+2);
}
```

Comment: where did you get this `main()` without return types and argument list from? This isn't C. Why is your question title about `printf` and not about your weird expression `**B+2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the dereference operator have higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than addition, so your expression is equivalent to `(**B) + 2`. In other words, when you dereference twice, you get `B[0][0]`, which is `2`, and then you add `2` leading to the end result `4`.

If you want `B[0][2]` then you should to `*(*B + 2)`.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up precedence, that plays a huge role in explaining _why_ this happens

Answer (score 5):

`**B+2` is equivalent to `(**B) + 2`

`**B` is equal to `B[0][0]` which is `2` in your array.

Hence the seen output.

If you want `6`, what you need is `*(*B + 2)`

More info on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Answer (score 3):

There are no brackets . So first the value of 1st element is first taken and then 2 is added to it therefore the output is 2+2=4 and it is not B[1][0] . When we use brackets *(*B+2) it first increments the address of B and then takes its value. Therefore it will then be B[0][2].

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of precedences. Try as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    int B[2][3]={2,3,6,4,5,8};
    printf("%d",*(*B+2));
}
```